# sails.js: how to update model

Tags: json, mongodb, angularjs, sails.js

Forgive my noob question. I'm using angularjs to send a user model (json) with varying fields. It works well with sails.js default PUT. I overrode the PUT, the problem is that I wish to update the model with the received JSON and do some processing on the modified model. Now I can't update the model with

```
User.update({
id: req.body.id
},{
req.body
}, function(err, users) {
// Error handling
if (err) {
return console.log(err);
// Updated users successfully!
 } else {
console.log("Users updated:", users);
}
});
```

Please help

EDIT:
After knocking my head on the wall for days, problem solved! I know, my code formatting here is not the best..

changed this:

```
{
   req.body
  }
```

to just:

```
req.body
```

(without the braces)

full snippet becomes:

```
User.update({
 id: req.body.id
},
req.body
, function(err, users) {
// Error handling
if (err) {
return console.log(err);
// Updated users successfully!
} else {
console.log("Users updated:", users);
}
 });
```

Thanks.

Comment: How is your question related to mongoDB?

Comment: The project uses MongoDb, that's how.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So you figured out your problem, sort of. *req.body* is already an object. But you really should sanitize it before you put it into your update and then save the object. There's a lot of reasons for this but with Mongo when you get only a partial object you'll replace the object in the collection which, in your example with a user, could be bad. When I send users to the frontend I cull off things I don't want transmitted all over like passwords. The other reason is the golden rule of web application development - never trust the client! I'd start with something like:

```
var user = User.findOne(req.body.id).done(function(error, user) {
    if(error) {
        // do something with the error.
    }

    if(req.body.email) {
        // validate whether the email address is valid?

        // Then save it to the object.
        user.email = req.body.email;
    }
    // Repeat for each eligible attribute, etc.

    user.save(function(error) {
        if(error) {
            // do something with the error.
        } else {
            // value saved!
            req.send(user);
        }
    });
});
```